# iOS hosted web page (user data backup/restore)

Tags: xcode, ios

I'm interested in implementing a 'user data' backup facility for the core data sqlite database within my application.

In applications like '[simple pdf reader](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/simple-pdf-reader/id311583355?mt=8)' you flick a switch in the app and are provided with an IP Address and port number.  You then enter these details into a computer browser on the same wireless network and can then get to a web page hosted by the device.  This real world example allows copy of pdf files to and from that device's app.  I'd like to use the same idea to allow back up and restore of the core data database file in future versions of my app ([iHeals](http://itunes.apple.com/au/app/iheals/id425233910?mt=8&ls=1))

I've no problem creating web pages, I'm just unsure on how to get my app to host one.  Any direction is most appreciated.

Cheers,

Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at implementing [this framework](http://code.google.com/p/cocoahttpserver/) or [this one](http://culturedcode.com/cocoa/).

Comment: neither of those links work anymore :'( Is everyone using iCloud to backup their Core Data DB's now?